# Android | Java | check if in GPS Android i passed specific location

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I want to check when i'm driving in my car when i passed specific location (LatLng).

I tried to calculate distances but eventually it didn't worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share any code?

Comment: Please can you detail what you tried thus far, it will help work out a good solution for you. Also what is the end goal? Do you want to know how close you came to a LatLng? If not then you will have to be in a ver specific location at the point of location refresh.

Comment: Hey , for now there's only the basic GPS code like this one (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Comment: @Numan1617 My goal is when i'm on this specific location OR passed it for example if i'm driving towards a building for some sort , when i pass it i will get a notification that i passed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refer the Location API to calculate the distance between your current location and another one.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

I think you can one of these methods:

```
public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)

public float distanceTo (Location dest)
```

Comment: Hey , i thought about what you said and it crossed my mind that if I'll calculate the distance i will get the calculated number but how would i know if i passed it.